# EU Blue card application from Italy

Tags: eu, indian-citizens, blue-card, italy

I've seen multiple questions regarding the EU blue card but I had additional queries. 
I am an Indian working as a User Experience designer in Italy for almost 2 years. 
I do get paid more than the threshold amount indicated on the EU website.

My question is if I were to apply for the EU blue card,

Do I need to get my Uni certificate evaluated? (I did a one year course here in Italy and I was informed that it is recognized by the Italian Govt.)
In the requirements, they mentioned that you have to work for the same employer for 18 months after you apply.  Does this mean if I have already worked 2 years for the same employer and apply for the Blue card, I must work another 18 months before I can relocate to another country? Or does it imply 18 months from the start of my contract?

Can anyone help me understand this?